# Do the Abhidharma texts exist online in original format?

Tags: reference-request, texts, dharmas

I just learned of the [Abhidharma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhidharma). What was their original or early language they were written in, and do they exist online in copy/pastable (non-PDF or image) format anywhere for free? Is [this](https://pitaka.lk/books/abhidharmaye-mulika-karunu/index.html#2) of any use?

So far people have listed some Theravada Abhidhamma links. What about the other schools of Abhidharma? Sarvastivada is supposed to be the only other school that has preserved a complete set of Abhidhamma, also with 7 books like Theravada. What languages are the original Sarvasitvada Ab. available in? And are there English translations?

Comment: Do you want the Pali / Sanskrit version or the English translation?

Comment: I am Abhidhammic entire life. I must say self reading Abhidhamma, either pali or translation, is leading the student to be confused and very misunderstood in Abhidhamma. I see many self reading people refer Abhidhamma content with many **serious mistake pali grammas, references, relationships, reasons**. They can make Sutta conflict with Abhidhama even the pali Abhidhammic scholars say "you are using wrong pali grammar, wrong words reference, missing some important translation, etc." So, I am very recommend to study with the Abhidhammic Tipitaka Memorizer directly, such as PaAuk Tawya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Theravada Abhidhamma, all Pali, only some translations, at Sutta Central:

https://suttacentral.net/ds

https://suttacentral.net/vb

https://suttacentral.net/dt

https://suttacentral.net/pp

https://suttacentral.net/kv

https://suttacentral.net/ya

https://suttacentral.net/patthana

Answer (score 0):

This site is pretty good.

Check out:
http://www.abhidhamma.com/Introduction%20to%20Dhammasangani.pdf

See also Anapanasati
(Mindfulness of Breathing)
Buddhadasa Bhikkhu Translated by Bhikkhu Nagasena
https://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/anapanasati.pdf

Comment: This is using PDFs, I want copy/pastable text :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there are a few different versions e.g. the Theravada Abhidhamma, Sarvastivada Abhidharma, Dharmaguptaka Abhidharma etc.

Here I focus only on the most popular version, which is the Theravada Abhidhamma.

If you read the [ATI page on Abhidhamma Pitaka](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/abhi/index.html), it says:

> The Abhidhamma Pitaka has a well-deserved reputation for being dense
> and difficult reading. The best way to begin studying Abhidhamma is
> not to dive right into its two key books (Dhammasangani and Patthana),
> but to explore some of the more modern — and readable — commentarial
> texts.

The page continues to provide a list of commentarial texts, some including links.